# How many characters is fscanf scanning in my code?

Tags: c

I'm using a for loop, which I want to iterate a number of times equal to the number of characters scanned by scanf. However, it seems to run too many times. The code was originally written to print to phrase "We are in 2019", which it does, but now I need to use it for something else. I added in the line: printf("%i",i);

to see how many times it was going through the for loop. It seems to be running 8 times for each run of the while loop, regardless of how long the word scanned was.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (46)); // create a char array

    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    fputs("We are in 2019", fp);

    rewind(fp); // sets to start of file

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF) {
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0]); i++) {
            printf("%c", word[i]);

            printf("%i", i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return (0);
}
```

The output is:

```
W0e1234567
a0r1e234567
i0n1234567
200112934567
```

So I can see it's running the for loop 8 times for each run for each run of the while loop.

Am I misunderstanding how fscanf works? i thought it stopped at a whitespace, and only stored the preceding characters... e.g. first it would scan "We" then store it as a 3 character array in "words", then scan "are" in a 4 character array in "words" and so on. What is really happening?

Comment: `sizeof(word)` will not give you the size of the array. It gives the size of the pointer. The size of the array is the `46` you originally allocated.

Comment: `char *word = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( 46 ) ); //create a char array` -- Why do this when you could have simply done `char word[46];`?

Answer (score 0):

It is stopping at whitespace.

Apparently you have 64 bit pointers.  The variable word is a pointer, so `sizeof(word)` is 8.  Since `sizeof` one character is 1, `sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0])` is 8.

So, the first time `fscanf` returns, it has read "We" into the buffer.  Then it loops for i from 0 to 7.

```
i = 0
printf("%c", word[i]); //=> 'W'
printf("%i", i); //=>0

i = 1
printf("%c", word[i]); //=> 'e'
printf("%i", i); //=>1

i = 2
printf("%c", word[i]); //=> '\0' so nothing
printf("%i", i); //=>2

i = 3
printf("%i", i); //=>3

i = 4
printf("%i", i); //=>4

i = 5
printf("%i", i); //=>5

i = 6
printf("%i", i); //=>6

i = 7
printf("%i", i); //=>7
```

so that is how you get:

```
W0e1234567
```

You would see the desired output if your loop looked like this:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    puts(word);
}
```

Comment: In other words, `fscanf` is working as you intended, the problem is in the code writing the output.

Comment: "_is working as you intended_" : only if the OP intended to also have undefined behavior, are you sure of that ? ;-)

Comment: @bruno I'm saying that fscanf not the part giving the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(word)` will not give you the size of the array. It gives the size of the pointer `char *word`.

It would be simpler to avoid memory allocation, and the size of the array isn't really relevant anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char word[46];                          // local array
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    if(fp == NULL)  {
        return 1;                           // or better error report
    }
    fputs("We are in 2019", fp);
    rewind(fp);

    while(fscanf(fp, "%45s", word) == 1) {  // restrict length, check the scan worked
        for(int i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++) { // finish when the string terminator is found
            printf("%c", word[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
We
are
in
2019
```

Comment: Note that I didn't check the return value of `fscanf` to be `EOF` but the number of items that were read. In this case where `%s` is used, it is unlikely to make any difference. But where you use `%d` it certainly does, because if alphabetic data is found it cannot be read and then `fscanf` does not return `EOF` but `0`, and good practice with the `scanf` function family is to specifically check the *number of items read*.

Answer (score 0):

Several remarks can be done on your code

- by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1, so your `malloc(sizeof(char) * (46))` can be simplified to be `malloc(46)`. Note you can also use an array `char word[46];`
- `fscanf(fp, "%s", word)` is very dangerous, if the read word longer than 45 characters you write out of *word* with an undefined behavior, limit the size doing `fscanf(fp, "%45s", word)`
- As said in the remarks `sizeof(word) / sizeof(word[0])` do not return the length of your word, you can just stop when `word[i]` is 0
- to print the index just after each character do not produces a very readable result, are you sure you want that ?
- why do you not directly print the word by *(f)puts* or *printf* with the format *%s* and get the length of the string using *strlen* (if you want to know it) ?

> I want to iterate a number of times equal to the number of characters scanned by scanf.

*scanf* scans more than the number of characters in returns in the string, the spaces are bypassed silently. Only one thing is sure, when you reach the end of the file without error the number of characters scanned by *scanf* if the size of the file.